# Cannot implicitly convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage'

Tags: c#, arrays, json, asp.net-web-api, serialization

I have the following Post method which I need to extract the list of objects from the jarray that it is returned in the response. 
I cannot get the return because of the error above in the title of the question.
Here is the method.

```
  public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostItemAsync(JObject obj)
    {

        obj = new JObject(
           new JProperty("name", "newname"),
           new JProperty("id", "1212"),
           new JProperty("identificationsIds", "12", "000")
       );


        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5001/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));





        var Res = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Member", obj);
        var MemResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.ToString();                
        var member = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(MemResponse);


        return member;
    }

}
```

}
I get the error in the "return member" where is throw the exception.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As the error says, you tried to return a JArray when your return type is `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`. Change it to `Task<IActionResult>` and return `return OK(MemResponse)`

Comment: Also change `var MemResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.ToString();` to `var MemResponse = await Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`

Comment: Why would you try to return JArray result in a method that its expecting a HttpResponseMessage?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that worked for me.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Seems like OP's problem is resolved.  Would you like to answer this, or would you rather mark it as typo / no longer reproducible?